# Not able to edit the entry inside the frame in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using a BindableLayout and inside that, I am displaying a list of items

```
<StackLayout
   BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding AccountsList}" Spacing="0">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Frame
                  Margin="0,5,0,10"
                  Padding="10">
                  <Label Text="testinnnng"/>
                  <Entry Text="{Binding UserText}"/>//this entry is not allowing the user to click on the UI since it is inside the list item
               </Frame>
          </DataTemplate>
   </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Here each frame is one list item.
The issue is inside the list item I have an entry box. But I am not able to edit the text. I tried all possible solutions given in google but still, the entry is not editable. I request please anybody help me on this issue in xamarin forms.

Thank you

Comment: are you saying when you run the App you are unable to type in the Entry box?  And that XAML isn't valid - I believe that Frame can only have a single child, and `text` is not a valid attribute

Comment: Which IDE are you using? VS would highlight that your xaml contains the errors that @Jason mentioned before even building.

Comment: I am using visual studio. The issue is once the list items are displayed in each list item I am showing one label and one entry. So when I try to edit the entry box or click on the entry box it is not allowing the user to click the entry. Could you please tell me how to make the entry enabled?

Comment: you should not need to do anything.  Is the `UserText` property readonly?  And please be sure the code you post is valid, it is very difficult to make suggestions when there are obvious errors in the posted code.

Comment: yes, user text is a property where I am binding the data to the edit text...on the UI the entry is showing with prefilled data which I am binding. But when I try to edit it is not allowing to edit the entry box.

Comment: is it a **writable** property?  And you still haven't fixed the problem with the Frame having multiple children.

Comment: I have given isEnabled=true, isReadable=false to the entry, but still it is not editable

Comment: that is not what I asked.  And your XAML is still invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jason said, the xaml is invalid. Put the stacklayout inside the frame first.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding AccountsList}" Spacing="0">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame Margin="0,5,0,10" Padding="10">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="testinnnng" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding UserText}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Info> AccountsList { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AccountsList = new ObservableCollection<Info>()
        {
            new Info(){ UserText="A"},
            new Info(){ UserText="B"},
            new Info(){ UserText="C"},
            new Info(){ UserText="D"},

        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class Info
{
    public string UserText { get; set; }
}
```

The entry could be edited now.

[image]